# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=50, address=0x113553871)

Tags: ios, xcode, exc-bad-access

I recently took over a project for an iOS app. I have very limited Xcode experience and am trying to learn, but I don't really know what I'm looking at when it comes to the debugging process. I was able to build and release the app several times in the past, but after a recent update I cannot build it for the simulator due to the error above.

[Here is my full log:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCqlJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at restarting Xcode (or even your Mac) deleting your cache completely including your derived data folder, cleaning and re-building. I've seen this kind of issue a handful of times recently and this has been the fix.

This isn't advice for how to actually resolve the EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue, I'm going off the assumption that it's actually a red herring in your case.

After doing this, if you're still having issues I'd try unlinking and re-linking my dependencies.